# Fastest remove directory under Unix

Tags: c, performance, unix

I am currently working on code that is quite sensitive to I/O, performance-wise, and I am looking for the *fastest* way to remove a directory under Unix from C code. I want to write something that works on all common platforms (Android, MacOS X, Linux), but I am willing to write different implementations for distinct flavors of Unix (I suspect that BSD/MacOS X and Linux/Android have distinct tricks).

Here are a few things that have crossed my mind:

- on all platforms, I can walk the directory structure with `opendir`, `readdir_r` et al, using `dirent->_d_type` to differentiate directories from files – this seems standardized under Linux, but not under MacOS X;
- under Linux/Android, if I choose this option, I can also use `dirfd` and `unlinkat` for fast removal of each file;
- on all platforms, I can walk the directory structure with `ftw`, using `flag` to differentiate directories from files;
- on all platforms, I can walk the directory structure with `fts_open`, `fts_read` et al, using `FTSENT->fts_info` to differentiate directories from files;
- I have not checked, but I have the impression that the BSD/MacOS X `copyfile` function can be used to remove a directory.

Is one of these techniques strictly better than the others? Am I missing something obvious?

Note that I am interested mostly in minimizing I/O and, more generally, system calls - I am not too greedy about CPU costs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably the *fastest* way to remove a directory is to not remove it :-)

Or, more exactly, defer it. If your intent is to simply get rid of (for example) `/home/pax/porn`, simply `mv` it to somewhere else on the same file system (`/home/no_user/junk/pax/porn`) and start a background process to get rid of it in a low priority process.

And by low priority, I don't necessarily mean CPU grunt, more that the process will do what it takes to minimise resource usage as per your needs.

For example, if you need the I/O effect of this to be spread out over a long time period, you could have the process delete files or directories with delays in between. While the I/O would likely be similar as if you deleted all the files at once, the measured I/O over short time spans would be less.

The advantage this method has is that, according to any process looking for the directory you've "deleted", it's gone, pretty much immediately.

It'll take a while to recover the disk space of course, since that's happening in a deferred manner, but it depends on your relative priorities whether that's important.

Comment: Your choice of example directory names may be offensive to some readers. +1 for the answer mind you.

Comment: "porn", in this case, is actually data files for studying progressive outer retinal necrosis, it was just a funny coincidence that the acronym came out to that - my wife would be rather upset if it was anything else.

Comment: I like your answer. Unfortunately, in my case, deferring deletion may have unwanted side-effects – some of the data is being deleted for privacy reasons, so informing the user that it has been deleted while it may actually be pending deletion is probably not a good idea (see e.g. http://www.contractoruk.com/news/002586.html ).

Comment: Actually, the only remaining problem is flushing everything when the process exits. Still important, though :)

Comment: @Yoric, your code doesn't have to lie :-) You can simply state that the data is being deleted and that they can carry on doing stuff while that happens. You can even send an email once done (or communicate in some other way), since the script doing the deletion can be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: Not in that case, I am afraid. Still, I have now implemented a deferred directory removal, with the ability to flush if the application exits before removal is complete, and to resume on next start-up if the application crashed before removal could complete. Now, I still want that flush operation to be the fastest possible remove directory, so I return to the original question :)